# how to apply mutli-threading for getting working URLs from list of 1000 URLs - Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Normally to check status code of 1000 URLs take 9hr 30 min
How can I apply multi-threading for these URLs, my output should be working URLs which will have status code of 200.
For example out of 100 URLs we have 70 with 200 code and remaining with 404 or anything else.

Input = ['https://xxxxxx1','https://xxxxxx2',..........,'https://xxxxxx100']

Output:- ['https://xxxxxx1','https://xxxxxx2','https://xxxxxx3',..........,'https://xxxxxx70'] these will have 200 status code

Comment: Check https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion of how simply thread works in python. You can use split your url list into two and then make two functions, which run on two separate threads.

```
import threading 
Output = []
List1 = [half of your urls]
List2 = [other half of your urls]  
def check_status(lst): 
    """
    Do you task
    """

def check_status(lst): 
    """
    Do you task
    """

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # creating thread 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=check_status, args=(List1,)) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=check_status_2, args=(List2,)) 

    # starting thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # starting thread 2 
    t2.start() 

    # wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
    t1.join() 
    # wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
    t2.join() 

    # both threads completely executed 
    print("Completed")
```

Once the threads start, your program also keeps on executing. In order to stop execution of your ongoing program until a thread is completed, use **join** method. Append the urls giving 200 status code to **Output**

Comment: how to append the urls giving 200 status to output list?

Comment: Use **requests** library to hit the urls and check their status code. If it return 200, do `Output.append(url)`

Comment: **Thanks** but from this approach as I mentioned for 1000 URLs it is taking 9h 30 min. So I need to use threads and finally how to append so that I get my desired output in above mentioned form.